# How to render elements in an array in different grid columns React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before. Anyway.

TL;DR: I have an array with URLs of images. How do I render every image with its URL (show each image) like this (my current solution is down below): [image: layout]

I'm creating an Unsplash API image retrieval React app and I've figured out how to get the photos, how to render them etc. What I'm scratching my head at is this: how to display them in a grid with 3 columns and no rows defined (I'll attach a screenshot of what I mean down below)? I use Axios to perform the get request and in `.then` I log the response in the component state array `(this.state.results` is an array) and I use map to loop through the responses and get the url. Basically this:

```
// the request
axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            this.setState({...this.state, spinning: false, results: response.data.results});
})

// the component render - this is the entire section where I will display the images.
// these are styled components
<ResultsSection>
   <ResultsDivGrid>
      <Spin indicator={loadIcon} tip='Loading photos...' spinning={this.state.spinning} style= 
            {{position: 'absolute', left: '50%'}}/>
                {
                   this.state.results.map(photo => {
                       console.log(photo);
                       return <ResultsPhoto src={photo.urls.regular} alt={photo.alt_description} />
                   })
                 }
  </ResultsDivGrid>
</ResultsSection>
```

This gets me the images in a grid fine. This is what I get:
[image: what I get]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your grid container:

```
grid-auto-flow: dense;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. It's the same as before.